# Which element of sentence determines relative pronoun?

Tags: pronoun, relative-clause

When I was in a course in Germany, the teacher explained like: “If a verb takes accusative then it also follows the relative pronoun.”

> Ich kenne den Mann, den an der Ecke steht.

Can somebody explain this rule please?

Comment: The rule is incomprehensible to me. The example sentence, in any case, is wrong; it should be _der an der Ecke steht_, with _der_ being nominative because it is the subject of the relative clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relative pronoun refers to a noun in the principal clause. The gender and number of the relative pronoun must be the same as the noun it refers to, but the case is dependent on which role the pronoun itself plays in the relative clause. Compare:

> Ich kenne den Mann, der an der Ecke steht. (*Er* steht an der Ecke)
>
> Ich kenne den Mann, dem du gestern ein Buch gegeben hast. (Ich habe *ihm* das Buch gegeben)
>
> Ich kenne den Mann, den du beschieben hast. (Du hast *ihn* beschrieben)
>
> Ich kenne den Mann, dessen Kind dein Freund ist. (*Sein* Kind ist dein Freund)

The same examples with a feminine noun:

> Ich kenne die Frau, die an der Ecke steht.
>
> Ich kenne die Frau, der du gestern ein Buch gegeben hast.
>
> Ich kenne die Frau, die du beschieben hast.
>
> Ich kenne die Frau,  deren Kind dein Freund ist.

Neuter:

> Ich kenne das Mädchen, das an der Ecke steht.
>
> Ich kenne das Mädchen, dem du gestern ein Buch gegeben hast.
>
> Ich kenne das Mädchen, das du beschieben hast.
>
> Ich kenne das Mädchen, dessen Bruder dein Freund ist.

Plural:

> Ich kenne die Leute, die an der Ecke stehen.
>
> Ich kenne die Leute, denen du gestern ein Buch gegeben hast.
>
> Ich kenne die Leute, die du beschieben hast.
>
> Ich kenne die Leute, deren Kinder deine Freunde sind.

Hope this helps

Comment: so we put main clause out and focus on relative part, right?

Comment: @Bergmann: For the purposes of case determination, yes. The gender and number of the relative pronoun depend on the noun they refer to, so, for example, *Ich kenne die Frau, **die** an der Ecke steht*